# How to fix string resource warning: "Placeholder name is missing"

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings, android-resources

In Android strings.xml file I have a string resource with two parameters like this:

```
<string name="menu_greeting_loggged_in">Hello %1$s %2$s</string>
```

The problem is that I have a Android lint warning saying:

> Placeholder name is missing.

Explain issue shows nothing.

How to fix this warning and what does it mean? How can I add the placeholder name required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled upon what I think may be the solution. Just add `<xliff:g>` tags around the placeholder parameter, like this:

```
<xliff:g id="HOURS" example="2 hours">%1$s</xliff:g>
```

So for your example above, replace the string definition with e.g.:

```
<string name="menu_greeting_loggged_in">Hello
  <xliff:g id="first_name" example="Jane">%1$s</xliff:g>
  <xliff:g id="last_name" example="Doe">%2$s</xliff:g>
</string>
```

The use of `<xliff:g>` placeholder tags is explained in the Android [Localization Checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html) (look under the section "Mark message parts that should not be translated").